# Need direction advice on javascript project

Tags: javascript

I’m working on a school project. It’s got to be done in about 10 weeks so I’ve got plenty of time to go about it.  I’m very new to javascript so that explains why I’ve got so much time given for it. I’ve laid out a concept I feel passionate about and want to do it.

What I want  from you guys are pointers, ideas or advice on what I should look into, maybe to do with specific functions or whatever, I’ll take any advice based on this concept.

The concept:

The project is a single page that shows a graphical design of the solar system. Planets that  spin around the sun and there are two or three interactive options  that I have to program. 
They are:

- When you click on the sun, the sun turns into a black hole that pulls on the revolving planets and they get drawn into the black hole with a nice little animation effect.
- When you doubleclick on the sun, the sun disappears and the revolving planets are free from orbit and just float into outer space, outside of the canvas of the screen.

What would you say I should look into to realise this project. Again, I’m very new to javascript so that explains my asking. Thank you.

Comment: This question will probably get closed because it's very open ended but here's what I'd suggest. Learn how to use [the canvas.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial) Don't worry about physics or anything yet, just draw the solar system at a static state. Next, learn how to move those planets, again, just do simple circles. Then use your physics knowledge to move the planets correctly based on gravity. Finally, wrap it all up with a click handler and you've got yourself a project.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into that. Yeah, I knew this question kinda doesn't belong here, I hope they'll leave it open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first piece of advice is ***do not delay starting the project***.  Especially if you're new javascript (or programming in general, as sounds like might be the case?).

Besides that, there are a couple of things I can tell you're going to want to look at:

- [DOM events/event handlers](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp)
- [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) is a really spectacular javastript library that you will almost definitely want to use.
- [d3](https://d3js.org/) is another library you may find helpful for your animations/drawings.
- You may also find [canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) helpful for drawing and animation.

Hopefully this points you in the right direction to start out.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll look into all of those. I was worried I might have made it hard on myself by picking such a concept, but it's about mentality. And you're right about the new to programming thing, but I'm a quick learner.

Comment: To be honest, I think you're going to have the most problem with the animations.  The interactions are fairly simple.  That's why I suggested d3 and canvas-- they're both fairly well known for animation stuff. But like I said, don't procrastinate (ask questions as soon as you have them-- don't sit on stuff for days!) and you should be fine :)